# How to return a variable from a module to the server in an R Shiny app?

Tags: r, module, shiny

I'm having a surprising amount of difficulty returning a variable from a module to the server in an R Shiny app. In a module, I'd like to return a value when a button press is observed, so I've wrapped the `return()` statement in a block inside `observeEvent()`. However, the desired value is not returned, the entire `observeEvent()` block appears to be.

I've attempted to create a minimal working example outlining the problem below:

## ui.R

```
# ui.R

fluidPage(
  input_module_ui("input"),
  actionButton("print_input_button",
               label = "Print Input")
)
```

## server.R

```
# server.R

function(input, output, session) {

  # Calling input module.
  input_module_return <- callModule(input_module, "input")

  observeEvent(input$print_input_button, {
    print(input_module_return)
  })

}
```

## global.R

```
# global.R

source("modules/input.R")
```

## input.R

```
# input.R

input_module_ui <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    textInput(ns("text_input"),
              label = h2("Input Text:")),
    actionButton(ns("submit_input"),
                 label = "Submit Input")
  )

}

input_module <- function(input, output, session) {

  print("I should only print once")

  observeEvent(input$submit_input, {
    print("Return input")
    return(input$text_input)
  })

}
```

When testing this app, I entered "test" in the text input box and submitted my input. However, when I attempted to print my input, instead of printing "test" as I'd expect, the following was printed:

```
<Observer>
  Public:
    .autoDestroy: TRUE
    .autoDestroyHandle: function () 
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    .createContext: function () 
    .ctx: environment
    destroy: function () 
    .destroyed: FALSE
    .domain: session_proxy
    .execCount: 3
    .func: function () 
    initialize: function (observerFunc, label, suspended = FALSE, priority = 0, 
    .invalidateCallbacks: list
    .label: observeEvent(input$submit_input)
    .onDomainEnded: function () 
    onInvalidate: function (callback) 
    .onResume: function () 
    .prevId: 1896
    .priority: 0
    resume: function () 
    run: function () 
    self: Observer, R6
    setAutoDestroy: function (autoDestroy) 
    setPriority: function (priority = 0) 
    suspend: function () 
    .suspended: FALSE
```

I believe that this corresponds to the last block in `input.R`:

```
observeEvent(input$submit_input, {
    print("Return input")
    return(input$text_input)
  })
```

How can I get this app to work as intended and return `input$text_input` when `input$submit_input` is observed?

Answer (score 9):

You were quite close to getting this to work. The trick with shiny modules is that passing variables into and out of them requires passing the variables as reactive values. I made two small changes to your code to get what I think you're hoping to see.

First was to return a reactive version of `input$text_input` from the server module (rather than from the observer itself, which should just tell the app what you want to happen):

```
input_module <- function(input, output, session) {

  print("I should only print once")

  observeEvent(input$submit_input, {
    print("Return input")
  })

  return(reactive({input$text_input}))

}
```

The second change is that now the output from `input_module` is reactive. If you want the values rather than the function contents, you need to resolve the object using `()`. So, in your server function:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Calling input module.
  input_module_return <- callModule(input_module, "input")

  observeEvent(input$print_input_button, {
    print(input_module_return())
  })

}
```

Output:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6796
[1] "I should only print once"
[1] "Return input"
[1] "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the code above to error out in my situation. Thus I thought I could provide a more generalised answer.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

lower_UI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    uiOutput(NS(id, "text3")),
    textOutput(NS(id,"verbose3")),
    actionButton(NS(id,"goButton"), label = "beep me", class = "btn-success")
  )
}

lower <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    retV = reactiveValues(output = NULL)
    output$text3 <- renderUI(textInput(session$ns("text3"), "test", "test"))
    output$verbose3 <- renderText(input$text3)
    observe({

      retV$output = input$text3
    }) %>% bindEvent(input$goButton)

    return(reactive(retV$output))
})
}

upper_UI <- function(id) {
  lower_UI(NS(id, "test"))
}

upper <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

  uRV <- reactiveValues(one = NULL)
  output$one <- lower("test")

  observe({
    print(uRV$one())
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  upper_UI("upper")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  upper("upper")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for what you've generalized here and why it's helpful? That will help future readers better understand how to apply these approaches to their own problems. Thanks!

Comment: I admit, I can't remember exactly why I said that. Looking at the code, my guess is that by returning a local reactive value (declared inside the server module) then there is flexibility about what we can do to that variable / how we update it.